# registering DI on generic typed class

Tags: c#, logging, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a generic typed class, which I am trying to inject logger, I have tried different combinations as in the bottom, couldn't find a solution.

```
public interface IFoo : IBoo
{

}

public class Foo<TResponse> : IFoo where TResponse : IFooResponse
{
     private readonly IAppSettings appSettings;
     private readonly ILogger<IFoo<TResponse>> logger;

     public Foo(IAppSettings appSettings, ILogger<Foo<TResponse>> logger)
    {
            this.appSettings = appSettings;            
            this.logger = logger;
    }
}


services.AddScoped<IFoo, Foo>();

services.AddScoped(typeof(IFoo<>), typeof(Foo<>));

services.AddScoped(s => new IFoo<IFooResponse>(appSettings, s.GetService<Serilog.ILogger<IFoo>>));
```

Comment: This is currently unclear. No problem statement as to what is the actual problem here.

Comment: problem is registering generic typed class(Foo<TResponse>) for ILogger

Comment: `new IFoo<IFooResponse>` trying to construct an interface. That will never work. Where is `IFoo<T>` defined? Make `Foo<T>` inherit from this and register the open generic types for DI. Then register an `IFooResponse` and you should be able to resolve `IFoo<SomeFooResponse>`

Comment: Your logger ctor param should be changed to `ILogger<IFoo<TResponse>>` also

Answer (score -1):

I will give you a simple example of how to create a service with Entity Framework. First we have the model.

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then we create the interface

```
public interface IProductsRepository
{
    void DeleteProduct(int id);
}
```

Then we create the repository

```
public class ProductsRepository : IProductsRepository
{
    private readonly WebApplication8.Data.ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public ProductsRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void DeleteProduct(int id)
    {
        Product product = _context.Product.Find(id);
        if (product != null)
        {
            _context.Product.Remove(product);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can add our service in the Service Collection

```
services.AddTransient<IProductsRepository, ProductsRepository>();
```

Finally you can use your constractor to get an instance of the service

```
private IProductsRepository _productsRepository;
public Constractor(IProductsRepository productsRepository)
{
    _productsRepository = productsRepository;
}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes